# Highcharts allowDecimals condition

Tags: highcharts

I need to have a check for the difference between y-axis values and if it is less than 5, set `yAxis.allowDecimals` property to false. How do I grab these `yAxis` labels values? Is there a good way to do it?

pseudo code:

```
if((yAxis.values[1] - yAxis.values[0])< 5) yAxis.allowDecimals = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by updating the y-axis when `yAxis.tickInterval > 5`:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

      if (yAxis.tickInterval < 5) {
        yAxis.update({
          allowDecimals: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zn9tadq8/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tickInterval` property which is the interval of the tick marks in axis units.

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [3,2,6,4,5,6,1]
    }]
});

console.log("Tick Interval is :"+chart.yAxis[0].tickInterval);

if(chart.yAxis[0].tickInterval<5){
  console.log("Tick Interval is less than 5");
  chart.yAxis[0].allowDecimals = false; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**API Reference**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval